# Force customized system class usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inherited

I created class MyToolStrip:ToolStrip{}. My project already has about 60 toolstrip instances.

Is there a way (except signature find/replace) to:

1. Force all my created forms to use MyToolStrip instead ToolStrip?
2. Force future MyToolStrip usage instead of ToolStrip (compiler warning is good enough but not the best)?

I believe there's no correct way neither to mark ToolStrip Obsolete nor to "override" or hide system class. So what is best practice? Thanks.

Comment: `Force future MyToolStrip usage instead of ToolStrip` - you may want to consider code analysis rule. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Too bad it doesn't rely on oop paradigm or at least compiler directives, but that's close enough, thanks! BTW, found VS2008 integration example: http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way (except signature find/replace) to force all my created forms to use `MyToolStrip` instead `ToolStrip`?

Not that I can think of - if your forms use a `ToolStrip` control there's no way to "inject" your control in its place.  Even if you tried to hide the standard controls with clever `#using` aliases, the designers by default add the full namespace to control declarations:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip toolStrip1;
```

> Is there a way (except signature find/replace) to force future `MyToolStrip` usage instead of `ToolStrip` (compiler warning is good enough but not the best)?

Again, not that I can think of.  If you had control over `ToolStrip` you could matrk it as `[Obsolete]` which would cause a compiler warning or error (depending on how you want to use it) but since it's a framework class you don't have that luxury.

IMHO 60 instances isn't too many to change via Find/Replace...